# Trigger addError method is not working from past 1 week on after triggers

Tags: apex, trigger

I have created a trigger which fires only after insert, update & delete on opportunityLineItems. I am checking if custom setting values does not exists then generate error. It was working till last week but its not working now.

**Snippet of code:**

**Apex Code API Version:** 28

```
   for(OpportunityLineItem record : newList){
        record.addError('No setting exists');
   }
```

Do anyone knows if salesforce changes anything in this context? I am not able to find? Or I am doing something wrong.

**I know as per Apex documentation 36 Version which says:** Use of addError(messsageString)on Trigger.new in before insert and before update triggers, and on Trigger.old in before delete triggers, the error message is displayed in the application interface.

> I am highlighting this : It was working last 1 week ago on after triggers.

Any help appreciate!

Comment: Now its not showing the error even if the custom setting is absent ?

Comment: Yes, previously till last week ago it was working.

Comment: I would be surprised if this is broken. Can you confirm that you are testing with default layout that would report the error or if testing with Visualforce that you do have an [apex:pageMessages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageMessages.htm) in your page?

Comment: @ajay Redundant question, sure that the code execution reaches that point? Only successful DML records are retained in the trigger.new in after context, if those records didn't successfully get into DMLed they wouldn't show up in your trigger.new context. Wild theroies though, sorry if it appears as not helpful. Thanks

Comment: @Keith C Default Standard Layout not VFPage.

Comment: @Stygon Yes, I debugged whole OpportunityLineItems are coming in loop,  reaches in the loop execution.

Comment: @TheAjayGupta
1. Did you change the trigger code recently ? 
2. Is the snippet you added is with in trigger or class method which is being called from trigger?
3.Are you sure that the list "newList" in the above snippet code has only trigger.new records?

Comment: @Maha, 1. No Change in trigger 2. Method is in class & being called in class method itself which is called by trigger 3. yes, newlist has trigger.new records.

Comment: The doc is in error  - if you use `addError()` in an after insert/update trigger context, the error `does` display on the standard user interface. I've posted doc feedback on this

Comment: @TheAjayGupta Could you share the structure of trigger and class methods involved in that trigger? I hope you checked and make sure that no changes done on method and classes recently.

Comment: Is there any new Process Builder related to that triggers sObject? I have encountered this problem when using `addError()` method and a Process in the same sObject, the error message never gets displayed to the end user, the process fails and the admin gets an email with the error message.

Comment: @Jose No Process builder & no any extra trigger.
Issue still persists.
What is your sandbox name like c6 ??

Comment: This is firing in an after context?  By that time it should be to late isn't it?